# MongoDB TTL Index Space Reclaim Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to implement TTL index on MongoDB and have few queries. I have been reading in forums and found post document deletion as part of TTL expiry, mondoDB doesn't reclaim the space.

Currently i have been using 4.2.9 Mongo version sharded cluster, does this issue exists in any specific version and is this resolved in any future version?

Please do help on this, didnt find much resource on this topic hence posting query here.